# How to use Sphero with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'am just trying to develop application with phonegap following this repository:

https://github.com/rossingram/Sphero-Phonegap-SDK

but this don't work!

I've found other library here but it's was useless!

https://github.com/OrbotixInc/HACKATHON-APPS

Comment: Please elaborate why did not work, it is hard to help that way. Also take a look at cylon.js however works with node.js.

Comment: I tried many time to implement you project with new android sdk, but i found so many error and I could not get it to work.

I found deprecated function in spheroplugin.java and in mainActivity. Especially the function StartupActivity.

I hope that you can help me because I not found nothing about it on the web.

Comment: i cannot use cylon because i need that application work on mobile!